# Javascript different ajax urls in test and deployment

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, tomcat

I have a very basic problem with my ajax urls. I think most people probably had this problem but I couldn't find the question in SO. The scenario is like this.

Assume I have a web project named MyProject working in Tomcat. And I have a service called myService which I call with an ajax request like below.

```
$.ajax({
    type : "GET",
    url : "/MyProject/myService/",
    success : function(response) {
// etc.
```

While testing in localhost I have to append the prefix `/MyProject` to url. But, when deploying the war file, I have to remove it.

It happened to me many times that I create the war file, upload it to remote server(takes about 20-30 minutes) only to see I forgot to change the url and wasted half an hour. What is the recommended way of handling this?

Comment: Is your war file not being uploaded to the parent directory of `myService`? Looks like your file architecture is different on the remote server.

Comment: @ElliotM Parent directory of myService is the root directory. On default settings of Tomcat, when you run a project in localhost url is not localhost:8080 but localhost:8080/YourProject. If I'm not wrong Jetty, for example, deploys it to localhost:8080, but Tomcat doesn't

Comment: I usually use a cookie to set various environments (e.g. 'env'=='dev') -- I can set all sorts of dev properties that there's no risk of them occurring in prod. You can get plugins for your browser that let you create cookies, and then use javascript to poll for the correct cookie/value.

Comment: The other alternative is create a build script that parses and removes all occurrences of that before you upload. Still have to remember to run the build script though ;)

Answer (score 1):

Could you just use a relative URL?

`"../myService/"`

Comment: This won't work. Url becomes localhost:8080/myService as expected, giving 404

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your page is JSP, you can use EL to get the appropriate value to prefix your URLs with:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<c:set var="contextPath" value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}" />
$.ajax({
    type : "GET",
    url : "${contextPath}/myService/",
    success : function(response) {
// etc.
```

This would resolve to `/MyProject/myService` in your dev environment and `/myService` in production when deployed at root.

Answer (score 0):

It's clunky, but JavaScript can access the full path of the page on which it is running (including the domain). You could call a function which returns the context path:

```
function getContextPath() {
  if (document.domain === 'localhost') {
    return '/MyProject';
  } else {
    return '';
  }
}
```

Then you prepend the whatever getContextPath() returns onto your URLs.